# NSData memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsdata

Instruments is showing that i get a memory leak right there:

```
-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone
{ 
    Layer *copy = [[Layer allocWithZone:zone]init];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:_image];
    copy.image = imageData;
    [imageData release];

    return copy;
}
```

The image property is declared as it follows:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *image;`

Here is a screenshot of instruments, to prove that i am not lying.

[image: Image snapshot]

Anyone see a problem in there?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the screenshot is for time profiling, not memory leak.

Comment: It's in the "Leaks" instrument, so I guess you are wrong

Comment: @DarkDust You say that you shouldn't autorelease it and I agree now because I understand why. But in any case the copy has to be released somewhere by the sender object. I haven't understood this part correctly, can you elaborate`??

Comment: 'To prove I am not lying'.... why would we think you are lying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how we solved it, following the instructions given [here](http://robnapier.net/blog/implementing-nscopying-439).

```
-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone
{
    Layer *copy = [[Layer allocWithZone:zone]init];
    copy->_image=nil;
    [copy setImage:[self image]];
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Leaks instruments shows you where an object originated, not where it "leaked". So somewhere in your code you'll have something like this:

```
MyClass *obj = [otherObj copy]; // or copyWithZone:
```

But you're not releasing or autoreleasing `obj` and thus create a leak.

In Objective-C, convention tells you a method should return an autoreleased object, *except* for methods that start with `alloc`, `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy`. These method must return a *retained* object instead and the receiver is the owner and thus responsible for releasing them.

See [Memory Management Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) in Apple's memory management guide.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that we do autorelease the copy, we found the answer, I'll post it later. It has to do with what it's being said here http://robnapier.net/blog/implementing-nscopying-439

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    Layer *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone: zone] init];
    [copy setImage:[self image]];

    return copy;
}
```